# How can I cross compile for Windows in Ubuntu using headers stored in /usr/include

Tags: c, linux, cross-compiling

I'm trying to build a simple app in C. I am using the libraries GlFW and GLEW, but I am trying to build for Windows so instead of `gcc` I am using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`. I installed the libraries using apt-get and the header files are stored in /usr/include and when I try to include them I get the error that they don't exist. When I added /usr/include to my include path I was getting a ton of errors because stdio.h is in both /usr/include AND /usr/mingwblahblah/include. How can I build this?

Comment: To successfully cross-compile, you need libraries for the *target* machine.  The GIFW and GLEW you install on Ubuntu from its standard repositories are for Ubuntu, not Windows.

Comment: In other words, you can't/shouldn't use headers in `/usr/include`. Instead consider using https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2 to install the libraries for mingw.